# Unexpected keyword argument in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu, pdf, savefig

I am trying to run python script for computing lipid interactions. The python script is downloaded from:
https://pylipid.readthedocs.io/en/master/demo.html

When I run the script, the following error keeps popping up.

###########################

TypeError: compute_residue_koff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fig_format'

###########################

I have highlighted the error line with BOLD in the script pasted below.

Following is the code:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

from pylipid.api import LipidInteraction

from pylipid.util import check_dir


trajfile_list = ["input.xtc"]

topfile_list = ["input.gro"]  

dt_traj = None  

stride = 1   

lipid = "CHOL"   

lipid_atoms = None  

cutoffs = [0.5, 0.8] 

nprot = 1   

binding_site_size = 4  

n_top_poses = 3     

n_clusters = "auto"  

save_dir = None  

save_pose_format = "gro"  

save_pose_traj = True  
                       
save_pose_traj_format = "xtc"  

timeunit = "us"  

resi_offset = 0  

radii = None  

pdb_file_to_map = None   
                         
fig_format = "pdf"  

num_cpus = None  
                 

#### calculate lipid interactions
li = LipidInteraction(trajfile_list, topfile_list=topfile_list, 

cutoffs=cutoffs, lipid=lipid, lipid_atoms=lipid_atoms, nprot=1, 

resi_offset=resi_offset, timeunit=timeunit, save_dir=save_dir, 

stride=stride, dt_traj=dt_traj)

li.collect_residue_contacts()

li.compute_residue_duration(residue_id=None)

li.compute_residue_occupancy(residue_id=None)

li.compute_residue_lipidcount(residue_id=None)

li.show_stats_per_traj(write_log=True, print_log=True)

li.compute_residue_koff(residue_id=None, plot_data=True, 

fig_close=True, fig_format=fig_format, num_cpus=num_cpus)

li.compute_binding_nodes(threshold=binding_site_size, 

print_data=False)

if len(li.node_list) == 0:

    
else:

    li.compute_site_duration(binding_site_id=None)

    li.compute_site_occupancy(binding_site_id=None)

    li.compute_site_lipidcount(binding_site_id=None) 

    li.compute_site_koff(binding_site_id=None, plot_data=True, 

fig_close=True, fig_format=fig_format, num_cpus=num_cpus) 

    pose_traj, pose_rmsd_data = 

li.analyze_bound_poses(binding_site_id=None,pose_format=save_pose_format,                                               

n_top_poses=n_top_poses, n_clusters=n_clusters,

 fig_format=fig_format, num_cpus=num_cpus)
```

#########################################################################################

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Please, fix the formatting of the script.

Comment: Hi Johan. I am using Python version 3.8.10 on my machine which has Ubuntu 20.04 installed.

Comment: You need the latest version of `pylipid` for the `fig_format` parameter.  The docs you linked start with *"This script works for versions later than 1.4. Please update PyLipID to the latest version"*

Comment: Johan, I am very naive to python. It would be very nice of you if you can tell how to update pylipid to the latest version.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `pylipid`. Maybe `pip install pylipid --upgrade` works for you?  You could try `import pylipid; print(pylipid.__version__)` to find out the installed version.

Comment: I tried getting the python version of pylipid. I have version 1.5.0 installed which suffices the version requirement.

Comment: Then maybe consider opening an issue on their [github](https://github.com/wlsong/PyLipID)

Answer (score 0):

I also installed the pylipid(version 1.5.0) and I met the same problem when running the demo code. So I checked the api.py of "pylipid" package and found that the functions in the "####calculate lipid interactions" of demo code didn't have parameters "fig_format". Maybe delete the "fig_format = fig_format" input in the "####calculate lipid interactions" can be helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The pylipid source code shows this argument was added in 1.5.10, so you need to be on *at least* that version.